# Flask / SQLAlchemy query in parallel thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

i have web application based od [Flask-Cookiecutter](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask). My app is synchronous, but i need use asynchronous request for progress bar with percentage progress.

For this request i need use SQLAlchemy on second thread (only read, without write).

When i try "traditional way": `User.query.all()` i get ony answer:

```
raise RuntimeError('application not registered on db '
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

Can you help me with this select?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Mh did you run `db.init_app(app)`?